# What do I need to start using specflow

Tags: specflow

I'm trying to use `SpecFlow` for a .net project.  I'm new to `SpecFlow`.  The Development team are using `NUnit`, so it would seem that `SpecFlow` would be a good option in conjunction with `Cucumber`.  However, the Development team have come back say that `SpecFlow` cannot be used saying they do not have an API/Service that is available to use at the level required.  Currently all of their automated tests are through the UI using Test Complete, I am keen to move to API level testing.

Can anyone explain to me why `SpecFlow` cannot be used, I'm sorry it's a newbie question but no one can answer it, I've asked everyone I can think of, surely the first steps would be to see if we can use `SpecFlow` with `NUnit` but perhaps not.

Can anyone give me a guide on my next steps, how can I be sure this isn't an option without righting it off without concern that it's just being blocked?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow has a unit test generator that generates unit test code for a variety of unit test frameworks. SpecFlow generates NUnit tests in its default configuration. The getting started page on specflow.org explains a quick way to get up and running with SpecFlow and NUnit, http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/.

If the UI is HTTP based, SpecFlow can be used with WebDriver or another browser automation framework to test the UI. This blog post provides an overview of how to get started with SpecFlow, NUnit and WebDriver, http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/enterprisedev/application-lifecycle-management/using-specflow-to/

I am unclear on the API you want to test. If you could provide more information on the specific API and UI you are trying to test, I could possibly provide some code examples or references for you.

- Is the API exposed through HTTP?
- Is the UI a web, mobile, or desktop
  application?
- Have you tried to use SpecFlow at all?

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow doesn't run tests. It simply maps readable language to tests.  If their test can be written as a nunit test, then SpecFlow is available to you to use. With no change, here is how it would look.

```
Scenario: Running 'testname'
    Then I execute the test 'TestName'
```

You would map that to

```
[Then(@"I execute the test '(.*)'")]
public void ExecuteSpecificTest(string testname)
{
   // Using reflection, execute the method listed
}
```

Obviously you would want to do better than that.  You want a given, when, then so you clearly show the setup, action, and then compare expected verses actual result but it isn't necessary.  Best practices however is another discussion.

To sum it up, code is code and SpecFlow simply maps to code.  You can use WatiN, WebDriver, or anything else to hook into the UI or an API.  SpecFlow doesn't care.  It simple executes the methods without knowing what's inside.